# Edit tomcats server.xml using ksh?

Tags: shell, unix, tomcat, ksh

I'm wondering whats the easiest way to change some settings in tomcats conf/server.xml configuration file through a ksh script?

For example, I want to change the default ports on these 2 snippets:

Replace this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

With this:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

And,

Replace this:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

With this:

```
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to change this in the config? This would be a simple sed, you can make it a bit safer by adding more than just the number:

```
sed -i 's/8005/8006' server.xml
```